# How to set constraint on input for fuzzing?

Tags: go, fuzzing

Assume I have the following structure

```golang
type Hdr struct{
  Src      uint16
  Dst      uint16
  Priotity byte
  Pktcnt   byte
  Opcode   byte
  Ver      byte
}
```

I have two functions `Marshal` and `Unmarshal` that encode `Hdr` to and from a binary format of:

```
 0                   1          
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|              Src              |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|              Dst              |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|  Prio |  Cnt  | Opcode|  Ver  |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

I'd like to use Go Fuzz to make random, valid `Hdr` instances, `Marshal` then to binary, `Unmarshal` the binary and make sure the output matches the original input.

The main issue I am having is that I cannot figure out how to tell Go Fuzz that fields like `Priotity` cannot be greater than 15 otherwise they will get truncated when they are marshalled (only 4 bits). How do I set this constraint?

## Update

This is just a toy case. There are many times with protocols like the above where something like the `opcode` would trigger secondary more complex parsing/vetting. Fuzzing could still find very useful issues within a constraint (IE: if Prio `0x00` and Cnt `0x2F` secondary parser will error because delimiter is `\` ).

Comment: I'm thinking Fuzzing may not be the best fit here. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT***

I'm not sure Fuzzing is a good fit here. Fuzzing is designed to find unexpected inputs: multi-byte UTF8 inputs (valid and non-valid); negative values; huge values, long lengths etc.  These will try to catch "edge" cases.

In your case here, you know the:

- `Unmarshal` input payload must be 6 bytes (should error otherwise)
- you know precisely your internal "edges"

so vanilla `testing.T` tests may be a better fit here.

---

Keep it simple.

If you don't want to "waste" a Fuzz input & you know the input constraints of your code, you can try something like this:

```
func coerce(h *Hdr) (skip bool) {

    h.Priotity &= 0x0f // ensure priority is 0-15
    h.OpCode %= 20     // ensure opcode is 0-19 

    return false       // optionally skip this test
}
```

and in your test - the coerced value can be tested - or skipped (as @jch showed):

```
import "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp"

f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, src, dst uint16, pri, count, op, ver byte) {
    h := Hdr{src, dst, pri, count, op, ver}

    if coerce(&h) {
        t.Skip()
        return
    }

    bs, err := Marshal(h)     // check err

    h2, err := Unmarhsal(bs)  // check err

    if !cmp.Equal(h, h2) {
        t.Errorf("Marshal/Unmarshal validation failed for: %+v", h)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just surprised the `Skip` or some sort of hack (`opver byte` to `op := opver & 0x0F ` `ver := opver >> 4 & 0x0F ` ) is the only way

Comment: `Skip()` predates fuzzing, so that function signature cannot be altered. Fuzzing is not precise, so I think this is the closest you can get.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify, the above is just a toy case. Fuzzing could still be very useful within a constraint for plenty of legacy protocols..

Answer (score 3):

In order to skip uninteresting results, call `t.Skip` in your fuzzing function.  Something like this:

```
f.Fuzz(func(t *testing.T, b []byte) {
    a, err := Unmarshal(b)
    if err != nil {
        t.Skip()
        return
    }
    c, err := Marshal(a)
    if err != nil || !bytes.Equal(b, c) {
        t.Errorf("Eek!")
    }
})
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, but still kind of feels like a band-aid as Id rather not have 50% of test cases be useless if i am only using 4 or 8 bits of a type.

Comment: Within the constraints that fuzzing implies (ie random input), you could ensure the byte values are valid by using a bit mask and `>> 4` shifting the random values. Other than that, I think it's better to just build a data-set in a loop and run each value using `t.Run()` in a standard unit-test